# C++ ADO access database output performance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, ado

I have program I created which reads a table in from access, process it, and then writes out a updated new table.  For 5700 records reading is done in milliseconds, processing milliseconds...writing out 5700 records takes about a minute for a local file.

I run each insert query through a sequence of:

`CoInitialize(NULL);

```
DBAccess.pConn->Execute(sql,NULL,adExecuteNoRecords);
```

CoUninitialize();`

sql is the char * string being processsed.  I would normally try a transaction block but that does not seem avialable with ADO and access.  I would try giving mulitple sql insert statements seperated by a ; but that gave an error extra characters after sql statement.  I am not connecting for each query...I connect once at startup.  Are there any tips for fast access output to a table from c++?

Comment: Performance questions without a complete code example that includes all of the optimization options used is almost always dead on arrival here at Stack Overflow because any attempt to answer requires an amount of guesswork that's not conducive to Stack Overflow's goal of providing high quality answers.

Comment: Have you tried to insert multiple rows with a single insert statement? Are you really calling `CoInitialize` / `CoUninitialize` for each insert as shown in your question but then you say that you connect once at startup.  If you don't execute the insertion SQL statement, how much time it take to do the insertions without that call? Is your database local or on the network? Many, many missing informations in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did some digging startiing here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-code-examples-in-visual-c?view=sql-server-ver16

And specifically I looked at this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortype-locktype-and-editmode-properties-example-vc?view=sql-server-ver16

I build a output process around this technique and the result was a time of 10 seconds which is about 6x faster than the execution of repeative single insert commands.  I think this is because your not interpreting sql to get the output operation done.